# How to align input type checkbox and the text aligned horizontally

Tags: python, html, css, django

Hi I have the following html code (used django framework):

```
<span>
    <button class="btn btn-default drop">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mera['{{ k }}']"> <b>{{ k }}</b>
    </button>
</span>
<br><br>
```

How can I align the checkbox and the text horizontally? Now the checkbox is displayed below the text. Any idea guys? Thanks in advance

Comment: Align horizontally Or vertically?

Comment: I think horizontally looks ok. https://jsfiddle.net/u9uLn2zm/

Comment: Its not really in single line Ketan

Comment: I am just curious as why do you have a checkbox inside a button? Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: @vellattukudy Its look Ok i have tried same code its working fine like as you want. even i passed long string in <b></b> tag its working

Comment: Yeah, am using bootstrap AKS

Comment: NIvedita, i think its because of the bootstrap version issue. AKS's answer is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the class `btn btn-default` I am assuming you are using bootstrap.

http://www.bootply.com/BLWQ53GPKL

Have a look at the code. It still includes the checkbox inside the button but using a `div` wrapper with class `checkbox` as shown in the example here [Checkbox and Radio](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#checkboxes-and-radios)

If you do decide to take the checkbox outside the `button` tag, you can look at the snippet here http://www.bootply.com/iqYiXeNZuo

Finally, for inline labels in checkboxes, radios:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mera['{{ k }}']"> <b>{{ k }}</b>
  </label>
</div>
```